# Machine Learning Keras accuracy model vs accuracy new data prediction

Tags: r, model, keras, prediction

I did a deep learning model using keras. Model accuracy has 99% score.

```
    $`loss`
[1] 0.03411416

$acc
[1] 0.9952607
```

When I do a prediction classes on my new data file using the model I have only 87% of classes well classified. My question is, why there is a difference between model accuracy and model prediction score?

Comment: Did you check the loss and accuracy of your model on a validation set?

Comment: Hi sdcbr, yes I checked by doing: model %>%  evaluate(x_test, y_test). test is refering to my validation set. It gives me 0.996

Comment: So is there maybe a difference between your new data and the train/test data you used? Maybe a difference in distribution?

Comment: can you please explain me more when you say difference in distribution. Is there a way to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 99% is on the **Training Set**, this is an indicator of own is performing your algorithm while training, you should never look at it as a reference.

You should always look at your Test Set, this is the real value that matters.

Fore more, your accuracies should always look like this (at least the style):

e.g. The training set accuracy always growing and the testing set following the same trend but **below** the training curve.

[image]

You will always never have the exact two same sets (training & testing/validating) so this is **normal** to have a difference.

The objective of the **training set** is to generalize your data and learn from them.

The objective of the **testing set** is to see if you **generalized well**.

If you're too far from your training set, either there a lot of difference between the two sets (mostly distribution, data types etc..), or if they are similar then your model overfits (which means your model is too close to your training data and if there is a little difference in your testing data, this will lead to wrong predictions).

The reason the model overfits is often that your model is too complicated and you must simplify it (e.g. reduce number of layers, reduce number of neurons.. etc)